# Proof of Expected value of Brownian Motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, finance

Consider the following exercise:

Let $T_{[-a,a]} = \inf \{t: B_t \notin [-a, a] \}.$ Show that $E[T_{[-a,a]}]$ $=$ $a^{2} \times E[T_{[-1,1]}]$.

Please tell me if this reasoning is correct:

$T_{[-a,a]} = \inf \{t: B_t \notin [-a, a] \}$
$ = \inf \{t: \frac{1}{a}B_t \notin [-1, 1] \} $

Then since the Brownian Motion is 0.5-self-similar we have:

$ \frac{1}{a} B_{t} = (\frac{1}{a^2})^{\frac{1}{2}} B_{t} =^{d} B_{t \times \frac{1}{a^2}} $

From here it follows:

$E[T_{[-a,a]}] = E[\inf \{t: \frac{1}{a}B_t \notin [-1, 1] \}]$
$ = E[\inf \{t: B_{t \times \frac{1}{a^2}} \notin [-1, 1] \}] $
$ = E[ {a^2} \times \inf \{t: B_{t} \notin [-1, 1] \}] $
$ = {a^2} \times E[T_{[-1,1]}] $

Can this be a possible resolution to this problem! Please give me some feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote seems entirely correct. An alternative way to do this is to actually  explicitly compute (takes even less effort perhaps). Note that $M_t = B_{t}^{2}-t$ is a martingale and set $\tau_n = \min(T_{[-a,a],}, n).$ Then this is easily seen to be a stopping time, as the minimum of a deterministic stopping time and the hitting time of an open set.

Defining $N_t = M_{t \wedge \tau_n}$, we see that this is a uniformly integrable martingale, since it is bounded by $a^2+n$. Therefore, we may apply the Optional Stopping Theorem to it. 
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[M_{\tau_n}] = \mathbb{E}[M_{0}] = 0
\end{equation}
Then, by monotone and dominated convergence, you may carefully take the limit as $n \to \infty$ and see $\mathbb{E}[T_{[-a,a]}]=\mathbb{E}\left[B_{T_{[-a,a]}}^{2}\right]=a^2$. Your result follows immediately.